# indexOf for the objects of the ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList where three objects are passed.

```
List lst = new ArrayList();
```

Here the instances are added through for loop

```
Circle c1 = new Circle();
lst.add(c1);

Triangle t1 = new Triangle();
lst.add(t1)
```

Now how can I use the `indexOf` method or other way to find out which one is the circle, triangle and calculate the area of both and store it in an arraylist?

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the error/non-required behavior in that?

Comment: using an interface with an `area()` method?

Comment: I have added these classes and stored in lst ArrayList. Now, I am stuck in calculating the area. I am running a for loop but don't know which object belongs to circle or triangle

Comment: indexOf or instanceOf ?

Comment: agree with fantarama: defining an interface is the way to go. Make use of polymorphism and avoid using `instanceof` because your code will get clumsy and verbose if you further add other kinds of shape.

Comment: agree with @tony200910041 too: i think that everytime you need an `instanceof` mean that you have a "bad" objects model

Comment: Actually I was trying from both method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `Circle` and `Triangle` classes extend `Shape`, you could try this:

```
List<Shape> lst = new ArrayList<Shape>();

Shape c1 = new Circle();
Shape t1 = new Triangle();
lst.add(c1);
lst.add(t1);

for (Shape shape : lst) {
    if (shape instanceof Circle) {
        // handle the circle
    }
    else if (shape instanceof Triangle) {
       // handle the Triangle
    }
}
```

Comment: Shape class can have an abstract method for area calculation.  in that case both circle and triangle can implement the area method to handle it in its own way. Thus, no instanceof checks will be required.

Comment: @NayanjyotiDeka Yes, and that would a good use of polymorphism.  The OP was very thin about implementation details and I did not want to assume too much.

Answer (score 1):

Just call "indexof()" method. It can finds.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Shape {
    Long area();
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
    public Long area() {
        return 0l; // your code here
    }
}
```

Same for Triangle class, then calculate area and put in another list...(java 8)

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add(new Circle());
shapes.add(new Triangle());

ArrayList<Long> areas = new ArrayList<>();
areas.addAll(shapes.stream().map(s -> s.area()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know that you will be inserting the `Circle` instances before the `Triangle` instances, then you can use even indexes to retrieve the `Circle` instances and odd indexes to retrieve the `Triangle` instances. Otherwise, you can loop through the list, check if each object is an instance of either class (e.g `obj instanceof Circle`) and then perform your area calculations.

```
for(Object obj : lst){
    if(obj instanceof Circle){
        Circle circle = (Circle)obj;
        // Perform the area calculations here
    }else if(obj instanceof Triangle){
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle)obj;
        // Perform the area calculations here
    }
}
```